# Add existing images from Media Library in to custom gallery

Tags: posts, images, gallery

I have `[gallery]` inside the post, and I'm interested in a way to add already existing images from media library in to this gallery? once I trying add any image I have only one option - insert into post.

Thanks in advance, Dmitry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, you can't. Galleries are tied to posts, and only to posts.

Options:

1. Insert the gallery from any arbitrary post, via `[gallery id="123"]` where `123` is the ID of the post.
2. Create a custom filter for the `gallery` filter hook, whereby you query/include the images that you want, perhaps by some post custom metadata (that you would also have to create)
3. Insert images individually, rather than as a gallery
4. Duplicate the images by uploading/attaching them also to the new post, so that they can be output via `[gallery]`